# How to use Rollup.js to create a common js and named export bundle?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I want to generate a single file to be used by an AWS Lambda using Rollup.js. The bundle must:

1. be commonjs;
2. have named exports;
3. resolve node packages and put all code in a single file.

I'm trying to achieve this but without success. My current configuration doesn't add Day.js code to the final bundle.

[I created a repository with my attempt](https://github.com/ttoss/poc-aws-serverless-rest-api).

### Some Considerations

#### Rollup and package versions

```
"@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
"@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
"@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
"@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.0.0",
"rollup": "^2.34.2",
```

#### Final bundle

[The generated bundle can be seen here](https://github.com/ttoss/poc-aws-serverless-rest-api/blob/main/rollup/bundle.js). I don't want these imports in the file:

```js
const tslib_1 = require("tslib");
const dayjs_1 = tslib_1.__importDefault(require("dayjs"));
```

Instead, I want all the necessary code from `tslib` and `dayjs` embedded in the file.

#### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is you set `tsc` compile your `ts` files back to `commonjs` causing the issue. This job is supposed to be `rollup`'s instead.

I would suggest you to leave `tsc` transpiles back to `esnext` (`esm` which is `rollup` needs), then you could combine all things with `cjs` style.

Here's the thing you might need to change:

```js
typescript({
  module: 'esnext' // change `commonjs` -> `esnext`
}),
```